# Constructor Has many Elements. how to refactor (Factory pattern)

Tags: java, constructor, factory-pattern

i am having a constructor with Factory pattern. i am passing to many parameters. how to refactor it.

```
ServerFactory serverFactory = new ServerFactory();
CalendarResults calResults= serverFactory.getResults(serverName,locale, Day, week,     
                            month,vdate,results,uri, EmailShare, inc, upperLimit, 
                            endLimit,exchWD, YearMonthDay,WeekMonthDate);
results=calResults.serverNameDay(serverName,locale, Day, week, month,vdate,
        results,uri, EmailShare, inc, upperLimit, endLimit, exchWD, YearMonthDay);

public class ServerFactory {
    public CalendarResults getResults(String serverName,String locale, String day,    
                     String week, String month, 
             boolean vdate, ArrayList<CalendarOutput> results, String uri, 
                     List<String> emailShare, int inc, int upperLimit, 
             int endLimit, NexWebDav exchWD, String yearMonth, boolean 
                     weekMonthDate){

        CalendarResults calresults=null;
        if(serverName.equals("www.google.com")){
            calresults=new Google();
        }else{
            calresults=new Exchange();
        }
        return calresults;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you All. i will try with value object and setting Multiple Time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to tell since you don't show all the code (I assume) where all these parameters get used.

But here are some things to consider:

- Replaces arguments of primitive type with value objects, this makes it much clearer what parameter is expected in what position.
- combine multiple related arguments to value objects. One example that seems obvious is upperLimit, endLimit (and maybe inc) which might end up in an object called Intervall.
- replace booleans with different methods. Often booleans are used to perform different algorithms. If that's the case drop the booleans an make seperate methods instead.
- If you have still to many and to confusing arguments, you might want to go with a Builder Pattern. This and the following blog posts might be helpfull: http://blog.schauderhaft.de/2012/07/29/named-parameters-in-java/

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple setter methods on `serverFactory` and those must be called before calling `getResults`.

If those are not called, `getResults` should throw an exception.

The sequence could be as follows:

```
serverFactory.setServerDetails(servername, locale);
serverFactory.setCalendarDetails(day, week, month, vdate, yearmonthday, weekmonthday);
...
...
serverFactory.getResults(results);
```

Answer (score 0):

Stringify all of the String parameters and split them into the constructor. But I recommend the current way that you are doing it. It's more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sending so many parameters, consider creating a [Value Object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_object) class, instantiate that and send that instance as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

One other way code be to use String[] for all `String` type parameters with little swap in the their position as below:

```
public CalendarResults getResults(boolean vdate, ArrayList<CalendarOutput> results,
                 List<String> emailShare, int inc, int upperLimit, 
                 int endLimit, NexWebDav exchWD, boolean weekMonthDate,
                 String... stringParams){
          //You may get your string params as
          //stringParams[0] -> serverName
          //stringParams[1] -> locale
          //stringParams[2] -> day
          //stringParams[3] -> week
          //stringParams[4] -> month
          //stringParams[5] -> uri
          //stringParams[6] -> yearMonth
          ....
```

While you can use the factory pattern as of now, with only change that all string type paramters are moved towards the end e.g.

```
   CalendarResults calResults= serverFactory.getResults(vdate,results, 
                   EmailShare, inc, upperLimit, endLimit,exchWD, WeekMonthDate,
                   serverName, locale, Day, week, month, uri,YearMonthDay);
```

Some level of simplification.